# Add new line to existing TXT file using SplFileObject

Tags: php, file

I have a TXT file and I neede to open it and add a new line at the end. I'm using SplFileObject:

```
$file = new SplFileObject( $this->fileName, 'w' );
$file->fwrite( 'my text' . PHP_EOL );
```

But deletes all the file content and only saves 'my text' inside.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SPLFileObject, but for `fopen()`, 'w' will open the file for writing but place the pointer at the start of the file. 'a' will let you append data to an existing file - maybe try that?

Comment: @andrewsi problem solved ;)! Using 'a' flag solved my problem! Thx a lot.

Comment: Feel free to add that as an answer and accept it when you can.

Comment: @andrewsi you have to reply as an answer no as a comment to accept it.

Comment: I was suggesting that you add your own answer, as you figured it out for yourself :)

Comment: But was your merit! Why don't you add the answer?

Comment: Because I'm terribly, terribly lazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I replaced the 'w' flag to 'a' flag. The 'w' open the file but place the pointer at the beginning, while 'a' place the pointer at the end.

Thanks to @andrewsi for this solution.